# How do I access a property from log4j.properties in a JUnit test?

Tags: java, logging, junit, log4j

I'm writing a unit test to validate some logging functionality by checking the log file. I started with the log path hard coded in the test case, but I'd rather use the entry for `log4j.appender.file.File` in the `log4j.properties` file, in case it changes. Is there a way to access that programmatically inside the JUnit code?

And in case anyone is wondering: the functionality I'm testing is all in `private`s, so I can't just check return values.

Answer (score 1):

You can access it *programmatically* using the following:

```
FileAppender appender = (FileAppender) LogManager.getRootLogger().getAppender("file");
File file = new File(appender.getFile());
```